# NotImplementedError: <class 'cleverhans.model.CallableModelWrapper'>must implement `get_logits` or must define a logits output in `fprop`

Tags: cleverhans

WhenI try to run from github.com/behzadanksu/rl-attack

python train.py --env Breakout --noisy --save-dir ./data/Breakout/ --attack fgsm --num-steps 20 --attack-prob 1.0

from cleverhans library, I get the following error. How can I avoid it?

> NotImplementedError: must implement `get_logits` or
>   must define a logits output in `fprop`

Answer (score 0):

Without the original code snippet that caused the error, my guess is that you are using a model defined in a framework that is not originally CleverHans and you tried to wrap it into a CleverHans model (it would help clarify your question) if you can post a snippet of code defining your model). If that is the case, then the error you are seeing means that the model class you wrapped your original model in does not have a method `get_logits` or `fprop` that is properly implemented. You either need to have a `get_logits` method that takes in an input tensor and returns the output tensor of the model, or a `fprop` method that takes in an input tensor and populates a dictionary with keys set to the layer names and values to the activation tensor of each layer. One of the keys of this dictionary must be `logits` or `probs`. You can find more guidance in the `model.py` file of the library: https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans/model.py

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The model is a trained reinforcement learning agent for Atari. Both of the following repositories are using cleverhans and in both of them after the latest update of the cleverhans, we get the same error.Any kind of help would be appreciated to solve the problem. Thank you very much in advance. github.com/yenchenlin/rl-attack-detection github.com/behzadanksu/rl-attack